# Can't read with IFS and read

Tags: bash

I have sequence of commands to find files with "actions/Auth" in code.
After I am using awk to split file path of grep output and finally I would like to
read line by line and instead echoing use sed `sed "s:from 'actions/Auth':from '../actions/Auth':"`

```
find src/ -exec grep -R 'actions/Auth' {} \; | awk '{split($0,a,":");print a[1]}' | while IFS= read r line do echo $line done;
```

The problem is third command as I need the paths which files to sed.

Answer (score 2):

you're missing the semicolons :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

funkyjelly nailed it - you need punctuation. See below, but -

Maybe it's simpler than all that.

```
grep -Fr 'actions/Auth' src/ |
  while IFS=: read -r file line # hope no filename has a colon...
  do sed '>your commands here>' "$file"
  done
```

This will probably be a lot nicer than spawning a separate `grep` for every file...

---

Also, "one liner" doesn't always have to be literal.
Sometimes you can read it better if you break it out.

```
find src/ -exec grep -R 'actions/Auth' {} \; | 
  awk '{ split($0,a,":"); print a[1] }'      |
  while IFS= read r line
  do echo $line
  done
```

Note that I changed *nothing* aside from adding whitespace.
As-is, `line` will never get anything in it, because it will all go into `r`...which I assume should have been `-r`, like this:

```
  while IFS= read -r line
```

though for what you are doing, as I suggested above, maybe it should be -

```
  while IFS=: read -r file line
```

As long as the filename doesn't have a colon, it doesn't matter if there's one in the line of data, because the rest of the input will still be dumped into the last var.